# If else statement on ForegroundColor SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I wanted to do a simple if-else statement on a button

```
Button(action: {self.theSoal = nomor.id}) {
            Circle()
                .frame(width:80,height: 80, alignment:.center)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .overlay(
                    Text("99")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                )
        }
```

see that .blue, so I wanted to a conditional statement of if the button is clicked then the color change from .blue to .yellow

how do I do it?? well so far my options are using a state?

```
state color = "blue"

if the button is pushed then color = "yellow"
```

shortish, but it's not good and I need to add the color to my self

so is there a way to deal with it??

This is how the button looks like
[image]

Comment: When exactly do you want the color to change to yellow? Do you want it to change the color to yellow as soon as the finger touches the screen, and goes back to blue when the finger leaves the screen? Or do you want the color to change to yellow forever once the button is pressed?

Comment: `.foregroundColor( isPushed ? .yellow : .blue)` where isPushed is a @State object that is toggled in the button action

Comment: can i do something simillar to  .foregroundColor( if state == self.num ? .yellow : .blue)

Comment: @Farhandika did you get your answer?

Answer (score 2):

## Persist Color

If you want to change the color and you want it to continue with that color,

1. First you need to define a `State` for the button
2. Then you need to toggle the state inside the button's action
3. And lastly, You make the color of the button conditional

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isActive = false // <- Check this out

    var body: some View {

        Button {
            theSoal = nomor.id
            isActive.toggle() // <- Check this out
        } label: {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment:.center)
                .foregroundColor(isActive ? .blue : .yellow) // <- Check this out
                .overlay(
                    Text("99")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Preview 1]

---

## Touch down color

If you want it to change color on `touch-down` and revert the color on `touch-up` then you need to define a custom style:

```
struct CustomButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment:.center)
            .font(Font.title.weight(.bold))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(configuration.isPressed ? Color.yellow : .blue) // <- Check this out
            .clipShape(Circle())
    }
}
```

And the usage code would be like:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Button("99") { theSoal = nomor.id }
        .buttonStyle(CustomButton())
    }
}
```

**Note that** you can encapsulate your configuration inside the style

[image: Preview 2]

Comment: does the state only occur on a single button or can i use it for multiple button (with the same state) ?

Comment: You ***can*** use it for multiple buttons but you **may** want to define separate `state`s for separate buttons.

Comment: is there a way to automate it?? like the app that i'm trying to create might have more than 20 buttons

Comment: something equivalent to this
```
.foregroundColor(self.theSoal == nomor.id? .blue : .yellow)
```

Comment: it is a valid code but you need something to trigger the UI update.

Comment: the ide gave me an error, looks like that statement isnt valid. so is there a way??

Comment: I think this is another question. Please feel free to ask a new one and post the error and more details there. You can put the link to the new question here so I can help you :)